# BackHandler.removeEventListener is not working in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to active `BackHandler` in one screen, based on the following code

```
useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler)

    return () => {
        console.log('Clean up ....')// this line does not fire
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler)
    }
}, [handler])

const handler = () => {
    Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to exit?", [
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            onPress: () => null,
            style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
    ]);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why did you pass `handler` function in the dependency array?

Comment: when I remove handler  in the dependency array, It does not affect

Answer (score 1):

based on https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler this one I am using

```
useEffect(() => {
  const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handler);

  return () => backHandler.remove();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler);
  return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```